Laravel is always returning local when checking the environment, even when tests are being executed
I've got a Dockerized Laravel app, here's the docker compose file:
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dmc
    container_name: dmc-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    # load development specific .env file
    env_file:
      - ./.env.development
    depends_on:
      - db
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
      - ./images:/public/images
    expose:
      - "9003"
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.2-alpine
    container_name: dmc-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - dmc-net

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.31
    container_name: dmc-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    # use the variables declared in .env file
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcd1234
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: development
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - dmc-net

networks:
  dmc-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-data:


When running my tests, ie docker-compose exec app ./vendor/bin/pest tests/Feature/ReturnsTest.ph, they are being run on my local DB which is MySQL and not using SQLite.
I added the following to one of my tests to validate what environment it is executing the tests in:
dd(App::environment());

and it turns out it is returning local instead of testing.
I haven't touched the phpunit.xml file, and I already checked and it is part of the container (docker-compose exec app cat /var/www/phpunit.xml). Here's that file's content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>

One of the suggestion I found online was to create .env.testing with the following elements:
APP_ENV=testing
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=:memory:

but that didn't make any difference at all.
Any idea what am I missing?
Thanks
Update 1
Output of docker-compose exec app php artisan about added:
docker-compose exec app php artisan about        ✔  8s 
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

  Environment ...............................................................................................
  Application Name ......................................................................... DunderMifflin-be
  Laravel Version .................................................................................... 9.40.1
  PHP Version ........................................................................................ 8.1.12
  Composer Version .................................................................................... 2.8.4
  Environment ......................................................................................... local
  Debug Mode ........................................................................................ ENABLED
  URL ............................................................................................. localhost
  Maintenance Mode ...................................................................................... OFF

  Cache .....................................................................................................
  Config ......................................................................................... NOT CACHED
  Events ......................................................................................... NOT CACHED
  Routes ......................................................................................... NOT CACHED
  Views .............................................................................................. CACHED

  Drivers ...................................................................................................
  Broadcasting .......................................................................................... log
  Cache ................................................................................................ file
  Database ............................................................................................ mysql
  Logs .................................................... stack / debug, info, warning, critical, emergency
  Mail ................................................................................................. smtp
  Queue ............................................................................................ database
  Session .............................................................................................. file


What do you have in your phpunit.xml? I know you didn't change it, but I have no idea what it has. Also, you never run php artisan config:cache, right? Run php artisan about and check if the config is cached or not. Nothing should be cached, run php artisan optimize:clear

Updated the question to include the contents of phpunit.xml and also php artisan about. No, I haven't run php artisan config:cache

Out of curiosity, can you move your .env.development to another folder that is not inside the laravel project? It should not exactly conflict in any way, but there is something really wrong in there going arround

This peaked my interest so I tested a bit and can confirm this behaviour.
Even using <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/> in the phpunit.xml doesnt seem to help.
Following the comment from matiaslauriti, I tried
php artisan config:clear

which did the trick. A half knowledge guess would be that the $_SERVER array is not re-populated within console commands.
You can add this to your CMD in the dockerfile
e.g.
CMD php artisan migrate --force; php artisan config:clear; php-fpm

thanks, i'll try that. I'm not so sure I understand the command you added. So the first time the container is created, it'll run migrations, clear cache and reinstate the $_SERVER array? what would happen when future migrations are run with the container up? do i lose again the contents of $_SERVER?

As mentioned the $_SERVER array is more a guess than anything. I just checked its value with php artisan tinker to see with config was set. The command runs the migrations, clears the config, and starts the server (if using php-fpm). If you use sth else the php-fpm would probably change. For your issue the php artisan config:clear part is the important one
